# iOS: UI (UIButtons) broke after using .getDataInBackgroundWithBlock

Tags: ios, user-interface, swift, parse-platform

In my storyboard I have a ViewController embedded in a NavigationContoller with UIButtons and draggable/clickable UIViews. The draggable Views get fetched from parse.com. In my text only version everything is working:

```
   query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println("DB Error: \(error)")
        } else {
            // Get data
            let fetchProducts:[Product] = objects as! [Product]

            self.products = fetchProducts
            self.loadCards()       
        }
    }
```

Then I extended this code with the abilty to fetch images from parse.com as well. I can see the images but my UIButtons are not clickable anymore. The BarButtonItem in the NavigationController works and even the draggableviews are moveable and clickable. I really don't understand why the buttons are broken. I see no related UIButton code in my extended code that could effect this:

```
    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println("DB Error: \(error)")
        } else {
            // Get data
            let fetchProducts:[Product] = objects as! [Product]

            // TODO: Fetching Images!!!

            let maxFetch = fetchProducts.count
            var maxFetchCounter = 0

            for fetchProduct in fetchProducts {
                let userImageFile = fetchProduct.image as PFFile
                userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        maxFetchCounter++
                        if let imageData = imageData {
                            let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                                fetchProduct.productImage = image
                                self.products.append(fetchProduct)
                        }
                        if maxFetchCounter == maxFetch {
                            self.loadCards()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I struggle already two days about this problem. I hope somebody can help. Thanks in advance.

[EDIT: 21th April]
I found another weird thing - if I exclude the code in an extra function then the UIButton is working again. But if I fire the function to often in a short time not all images will be there.

```
    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println("DB Error: \(error)")
        } else {
            // Get data
            let fetchProducts:[Product] = objects as! [Product]

            self.products = fetchProducts
            self.updateImageFromParse()
        }
    }
```

and the ne functions

```
func updateImageFromParse() {
    let maxFetch = self.products.count
    var maxFetchCounter = 0


    println("Get Images")
    for fetchProduct in self.products {
        let userImageFile = fetchProduct.image as PFFile
        userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                maxFetchCounter++
                println("Count: \(maxFetchCounter)/\(maxFetch)")
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    fetchProduct.productImage = image
                } else {
                    println("ERROR: NO PICTURE !!!!!")
                }
                if maxFetchCounter == maxFetch {
                    self.loadCards()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I even haven't no idea why the UIButtons are working if I exclude the code in a function :/

Comment: In this code, nowhere do I see references to a navigation controller, so I'm pretty confused...

Comment: The code is only a part of my whole ViewController. It has nothing to do with this snippet. I just mentioned it because the BarButtonItems are working ... only the UIButton in my view of the VC is not clickable after I add my image fetch :(

Comment: where are these query fetches taking place? Are these happening in viewDidLoad?